# how to speed up receiving posts from telegram channels

Tags: python, parsing, telethon

I made a telethon program that parses messages from the list of channels into telegram, but the problem is that the parser reacts to the post only when it comes to the account with which I originally logged in. Sometimes posts come with a delay due to the fact that I'm not sitting in the telegram, but you need to make sure that you respond to messages as quickly as possible. How can this be done?